# Singular matrix while calculating p-value in Linear Regression

Tags: determinant, regression, linear-regression, python, p-value

So I am calculating p-values in a Linear regression problem. I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69095315/13963610) for reference.
Here as you can see there is one calculation

```
beta_cov = np.linalg.inv(X1.T@X1)
```

Which is nothing but the inverse of the dot product of (transpose of the independent variable matrix(X) and the matrix itself.
example X in numpy format

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 3.840e+00, 5.260e+02, 5.970e+02, 8.100e+01,
        ....]])
```

Now if you try to calculate the `beta_cov`  it will throw an error like `Singular matrix` because the determinant of the dot(X.T, X) is zero.

```
np.linalg.det(arr .T@narr) # det is 0
```

Now I am facing one problem. So as X is a feature matrix, X is like [independent_vector1, independent_vector2, independent_vector3,...,independent_vectorn]. Now while doing linear regression the position of the vecor does not matter, so it can be `[independent_vector2, independent_vector1, independent_vector3,...,independent_vectorn-4]`. But interestingly if you rearrange the columns of the above mentioned X, the determinant becomes non zero like

```
new_arr = arr[:,[0,3,13,14,7,8,9,6,5,4,11,12,1,10,2]] #changing the column position
np.linalg.det(new_arr .T@new_arr) #det is 1.7583201199503196e+20
```

Now I am confused, the position of the features should not affect the calculation. X[feature1, feature2, feature3] is effectively the same as X[feature2, feature1, feature3] etc...Then why is it affecting the p-value calculation? Does that mean the features are highly correlated and they are not mutually orthogonal?

Comment: You probably have some features that are highly correlated. Some algorithms can break under imperfect multicollinearity, or give you different values for matrix manipulations as you reorder columns, like different standard errors for regression coefficients, or in your case, determinants. Try running a regression with a column ordering that has a nonzero determinant, and then take a closer look at the coefficients with large standard errors - that's how multicollinearity reveals itself.

Comment: okay, let me try to remove one of the correlated columns.

Comment: ya, after removing one pair of the columns which are correlated by more than or equals to 90%, it seems working.